# How to use nth-child on a filtered list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-isotope

I am pulling a list of images/items from a database and filtering them based on category.

The design requirements are a tiled/mosaic layout with a large square on the 7th item, and a larger rectangle on the 8th item, on ALL filters. Meaning the larger squares cannot be in a different order.

Currently my approach is to use nth-child selectors to select the 7th and 8th from the list of items:

```
/* create big item block */
.grid-item:nth-child(7n) { 
  height: 24em;
  width: 50%; 
}
/* create rectangle item block */
.grid-item:nth-child(8n) { width: 50%; }
```

This is a problem since it only affects the overall list. How can I target the 7th and 8th item in the filtered list after the button/category is selected?

Here is a codepen with the correct layout I am trying to achieve for the view-all filter. I am trying to achieve this same layout but with different items based off the filter. If you select 'thank-you' category, you can see the big square is pulled into the 3rd place on this list and still remains a large square due to the nth-child selector.

http://codepen.io/H0BB5/pen/BLNLWy

Comment: It's not possible to use the nth-child whitout counting the hidden elements with just CSS

Comment: Depending on how you create the list, you could try adding classes to add specificity. In once project I did, I also had an odd structure in which I had to alternate the background for each row but there were also hidden rows. I'd suggest maybe adding a "visibility" class to the ones you want to count.

Comment: Just the 7th and 8th items, or do you want the pattern to repeat - 15th and 16th, 23rd and 24th etc?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 just the 7th and 8th! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is twofold :

- isotope does not removed filtered-out items, rather hides them with `display:none`. therefore items remain selectable by the `nth-child()` selectors in CSS.
- resizing of items needs to be performed *before* the grid is rearranged, hence before `grid.isotope({filter: ...})` is called.

As a consequence, CSS won't do the job on its own. A little more javascript is required.

One approach would be :

- to set up an 'arrangeComplete' event handler to resize the grid items and call `grid.isotope()` to rearrange them,
- call `grid.isotope({ filter: ... })` and allow the event handler to fire after the filter has been applied.

This will kind of work but the user will see the double-rearrangement.

```
// bind filter button click
$('#filters').on('click', 'button', function() {
    var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    grid.one('arrangeComplete', function(event, laidOutItems) {
        // Triggered after a layout and all positioning transitions have completed.
        $('.grid .grid-item').filter(':visible').removeClass('big rectangle')
            .eq(6).addClass('big') // the 7th item
            .end()
            .eq(7).addClass('rectangle'); // the 8th item
        grid.isotope(); // re-trigger isotope
    });
    grid.isotope({ filter: filterFns[filterValue] || filterValue });
}).find('button').eq(0).trigger('click');// trigger click on default button to initialize everything.
```

For a better visual effect, you can get smart :

- "pre-apply" the filter manually, *without applying isotope's filter*, by filtering a jQuery collection comprising all items in the grid,
- still in the jQuery collection, select the 7th/8th items (from those that *will be* visible) and resize them,
- finally, using the same filter again, call `grid.isotope({filter: ...})` to actually rearrange the grid.

Thus, the grid is rearranged just once and the visual effect will be more pleasing.

Fortunately, jQuery chaining makes the code reasonably trivial :

```
// bind filter button click
$('#filters').on('click', 'button', function() {
    var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    grid.find('.grid-item')
        .removeClass('big rectangle')
        .filter(filterFns[filterValue] || filterValue)
        .eq(6).addClass('big') // the 7th item
        .end()
        .eq(7).addClass('rectangle') // the 8th item
    grid.isotope({ filter: filterFns[filterValue] || filterValue });
}).find('button').eq(0).trigger('click');// trigger click on default button to initialize everything.
```

**[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/87vpggyd/)**

In both approaches, replace the two '.grid-item:nth-child' directives in the style sheet with :

```
.grid-item.big { 
  height: 24em;
  width: 50%; 
}
.grid-item.rectangle { width: 50%; }
```

Note: To style just the 7th/8th items, and not the 15th/16th, 23rd/24th etc, *don't use nth-child*.

Comment: hey roamer, this is a really clever way of doing it. 
It works great, all but the rectangle for some reason doesn't seem to be applying. here is an updated pen - http://codepen.io/H0BB5/pen/JRdrZZ?editors=1010

Comment: This is sweet. So what's the best way to add in a loop to support 7n? Learning a lot here [edit: Oh nm just saw @h0bb5's comment about that. h0bb5 could you update the question? That makes a big difference]

Comment: Sorry @henry, "... which the OP says is not the case. ..."

Comment: (I think you thought I was h0bb5 there [edit: ha yep np]) but also, looks like that `.next()` should be `.nextAll(filterValue).eq(0)`

Comment: @henry, no because `.next()` operates on the already filtered jQuery collection. The filter doesn't need to be applied again.

Comment: You would think, right? I would think. But if you add in a few `<div class="grid-item thank-you"></div><div class="grid-item"></div>` and then try the "Thank You" filter you'll see. e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/enry/80park9o/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122878/discussion-between-roamer-1888-and-henry).

Comment: @henry is right about `.next()` not working. I can't quite see why though it must be simple. I have edited the answer with something that works.

Comment: And added a link to a demo.

Comment: Sorry guys, I signed off for the night. Roamer, your answer works perfectly now! Thank you, and thank you @henry for all of your help and debugging Roamer's a bit. I learned heaps. Thanks again!